# How to convert vector<vector<int>>to int**？

Tags: c++

vectoris easy to obtain int* through vector::data(), so how to convert vector<vector>to int**?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int **t;
     t = reinterpret_cast<int **>(std::data(temp));
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
         {
             std::cout << t[i][j] << "    ";
         }
     }
}
// out : 1    2    3    0    0    0
```

It's obviously wrong.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the actual problem that conversion is supposed to solve?

Comment: As for your current code, `std::data(temp)` is the same as `temp.data()` which returns a pointer to its first element. Since the elements of the `temp` vector is a `std::vector<int>`, that what you get a pointer to.

Comment: Some old codes are used in projects, which need to be like int * * parameters, but I want to make the new code more elegant.

Comment: @jack: You want to verify if the old code was precise with its types. It might actually need only an `int* const*` - i.e. it can change `int` values but not `int*` pointers. This matters, because you can't directly change the `int*` where a `std::vector` stores its data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple "trick" to create the pointer that you need, as a temporary workaround while the code is being refactored to handle standard containers (which is what I really recommend that you should do).

The vectors [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function returns a pointer to its first element. So if we have a `std::vector<int>` object, then its `data` function will return an `int*`. That puts us about halfway to the final solution.

The second half comes by having a `std::vector<int*>`, and using its `data` function to return an `int**`.

Putting this together, we create a `std::vector<int*>` with the same size as the original `std::vector<...>` object, and then initialize all elements to point to the sub-vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp;

// ...

// Create the vector of pointers
std::vector<int*> pointer_vector(temp.size());

// Copy the pointers from the sub-vectors
for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i)
{
    pointer_vector[i] = temp[i].data();
}
```

After the above loop, then you can use `pointer_vector.data()` to get the `int**` pointer you need.

---

Until you have refactored the code, you could put this in an overloaded function that does the conversion and calls the actual function:

```
// The original function
void some_function(int**);

// Creates a vector of pointers, and use it for the
// call of `some_function(int**)`
void some_function(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& actual_vector);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, but is it necessary to traverse the vector to delete the pointer?

Comment: @jack, the vector will delete all pointers when it goes out of scope. You're just accessing the data via the pointers, but you're not taking the ownership of its lifespan through this method.

Comment: @jack You don't delete pointers in C++. You delete objects, by using pointers. You do not need to delete a vector's data because the vector does that by itself when the vector is deleted.